# Repeatable content in uiscrollview - Swift

Tags: swift

I am wondering if someone can guide me in the right direction.

I am laying out a uiview with 2 uiscrollviews. 1 is vertical and the other, half way down the view, is horizontal.

I have the structure set up as in I can scroll down to the horizontal one and then I can scroll horizontally 5 pages (hardcoded). The horizontal scrollview has paging enabled and takes up the full width of the screen (auto layout). All this works fine. The uiscrollview is contained within a uiview with constraints.

Each of the 5 (pages) subviews contain the same elements (date, name, title, image etc all centered) however the content is being parsed from coredata. Page 1 = Joe, Page 2 = Jane etc

The part I am having trouble working out is how to build these essentially subviews. If I put a label in the uiscrollview this scrolls off the screen on page 2. What would you suggest is the best way to handle having 5 (or 10) pages in a scrollview with the same elements but different content?

Any recommendations is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, take a look at `UICollectionView`s. They're quite involved, but they act like a super-powered `UITableView`s that can do pretty much anything (including rudimentary pagination and horizontal/vertical scrolling.

Try setting it up `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with a single row and make the elements fill the whole page (for example, use `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize` to dynamically size the cells to fill your view port)
and then just subclass `UICollectionViewCell` to be the kind of "page" that you want.

This is a little involved, and you'll be reading a lot of [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) but this is probably best way to do what you want, and it's easily extensible if you decide you want more than 5-10 pages or you want to add more UI to each page.

A simpler alternative, that isn't as flexible, is to make a `UIView` subclass with a method/initializer for populating it with the data you need, and then just run a for-loop over all your data, creating pages inside the `UIScrollView` where the frame for each is `CGRect(x: screenWidth * i, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: yourHeight)`, where `i` is your for-loop variable, so that the pages sit edge to edge and fill the screen. Adjust formula depending on your own situation of course.

---

After re-reading your question it might just be that you want a static label that changes *its* content depending on the content in the page that is scrollable behind it. To do that add the `UILabel` as a child-view to the same parent view that holds the scrollView, adding it *after* the `UIScrollView` (or just call `bringSubviewToFront` to bring it's z-index forward) so that it's position is independent of the scrollView. To have it update with the page-scrolls, hook into `func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)` and calculate the page from the `targetContentOffset` via

```
let offset = targetContentOffset.memory
let page = Int(offset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
```

And then populate the label from your Data Array using the page as the index (but make sure to check Array bounds, as scrolling past either edge could yield a `-1` or a `array.count` or even more).

Happy coding, sorry for the multitude of options! Let me know if I still didn't answer your question

Comment: Thanks for those options. I tried a static label but it didn't "scroll" across and didn't look great. I just found something that uses multiple uiviews in a for loop. I will give that a go but still seems quite involved and not sure how it will work with auto layout. I will also read up on collection views. Sound promising.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions. I have the option where I create multiple subviews, get their width and set the scroll view. Everything is working great.